# Run a serverside port-check using an HTML button?

Tags: html, web, port, ping

I apologise if my question wasn't worded correctly, I wasn't sure how to put it. Also forgive me if it isn't in HTML and turns out to be some other web scripting language. I don't know the capabilities of PHP or ASP or ColdFusion etc etc.

What I'm trying to do is have a page on my web server that when a user clicks a button on the page, the server will check if a port is running on it's own IP with a preset port for each button, I want multiple buttons with the same IP but different ports to be pinged.

Example: Button 1 (Terraria Server) is clicked, server pings 127.0.0.1:7777 and tells the user if it gets a response or not.
Button 2 (Minecraft Server) is clicked, server pings 127.0.0.1:25565 and tells the user etc etc.

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with HTML.  As you said, you need to do this server-side, and HTML does not run server-side.  HTML is nothing but a document format.  Please pick a server-side technology and ask a specific question for that technology.  Any of them should be able to accomplish this task.  Also be specific as to what you mean by "check if a port is running"... a port doesn't run anything.  Are you trying to check to see if something is listening on that port?  Or if you can connect to that port?  And if you can connect to it, clarify what specifically you want to verify.

Comment: The best you can do is run something like `nmap` against the IP of the person visiting the website you're trying to create. This may not work the way you intend it though. You can try it with any server side technology, but it's not all that beginner friendly.

Comment: Brad, can you suggest a serverside language to use? And by 'check if a port is running' I meant check to see if there is a server running and listening on that port. I run multiple game servers from my machine and I just want an easy way for my clients to see which servers are up and which servers are down based on the port they are running from. Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in HTML. If you are working with PHP, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300255/see-if-a-server-is-listening-on-a-port-in-php?rq=1) for your answer.