# See if a server is listening on a port in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, port

Before answering, please note that I am completely new to PHP. I have heard it is powerful.

What I'm trying to do is have a page on my (Apache 2) web server that when a user clicks a button on the page, the server will check if a port is running on it's own IP with a preset port for each button, I want multiple buttons with the same IP but different ports to be pinged.

Example:

- Button 1 (Terraria Server) is clicked, server pings 127.0.0.1:7777 and tells the user if it gets a response or not.
- Button 2 (Minecraft Server) is clicked, server pings 127.0.0.1:25565 and tells the user etc etc.

I already have PHP installed and working, all I need is some code :)

Comment: Open a socket on the port (there's billions of Google results for this) and if you can open the socket you know the port is running. Do note that some services (eg. IMAP IIRC) will ban you if you do this too much ("*why is this IP starting a conversation with me and not saying anything?!*")

Comment: @h2ooooooo Well I am running the server on my home computer, I'm not expecting much traffic so that's why that's that. I will be using it to ping itself on different ports. Not another server. It's completely local.

Comment: Check out [`fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 7777, $errorNumber, $errorString, 5)`](http://www.php.net/fsockopen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempt a connection on the port and return the result:

```
 <?php
     function Connect($port) {
        $serverConn = @stream_socket_client("tcp://127.0.0.1:{$port}", $errno, $errstr);
        if ($errstr != '') {
            return false;
        }
       fclose($serverConn);
       return true;
      } 


    if(isset($_POST['portTest'])){
       switch ($_POST['portTest']){
           case 'minecraft': $port= '25565';
        break;
           case 'Terraria': $port= '7777';
        break;  
           default: exit;
       }
     if (Connect($port)){
         echo "Server is running!";
       }else{
         echo "Server is down";
       }
    }
    ?> 

    <form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="portTest" value="minecraft">
    <input type="submit" name="portTest" value="Terraria">
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it worked the way I wanted it to :D
I just want to ask, is there a way to make the timeout shorter? I couldn't find an obvious way. It's just that if the server is down, the page will refresh for about 15-20 seconds, which isn't that good.

Comment: Yes, the 4th parameter is the timeout so `@stream_socket_client("tcp://127.0.0.1:$port", $errno, $errstr,5);` would give a 5sec timeout